# jQuery XML to String with XMLSerializer: FF throws security error

Tags: jquery, xml, xmlserializer

I've been trying to serialize an XML (jQuery object) to string to POST it to server.

```
<script>
$(function(){
  myxml = "<tag>just a sample here</tag>";
  myxml = $(myxml);
  if (window.ActiveXObject){
      var xmlString = myxml.xml;
  } else {
    var oSerializer = new XMLSerializer();  
    var xmlString = oSerializer.serializeToString(myxml); 
  }
  console.log(xmlString);
}
</script>
```

This code doesn't work. FF throws a security error (didn't check other browsers, but it is already enough that FF doesn't run this script).

Comment: Your code is invalid. The `$(` is not properly closed with a `)`.

Comment: Found the root of the problem.

The problem was that XMLSerializer can't eat jQuery, it can be fed only with real XML objects. Feeding it with myxml[0] instead of myxml helped:

<script>
$(function(){
  myxml = "<tag>just a sample here</tag>";
  myxml = $(myxml);
  if (window.ActiveXObject){
      var xmlString = myxml.xml;
  } else {
    var oSerializer = new XMLSerializer();  
    var xmlString = oSerializer.serializeToString(myxml[0]); 
  }
  console.log(xmlString);
})
</script>

Comment: you can answer your own question and mark it correct so that somebody else facing same problem would know what solved it...

Comment: thanks 3nigma, just've done it (see below) =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to sum up the experience.

Adding [0] to jQuery selector helped to address XML-type object (see my comments above):

```
<script>
$(function(){ 
  myxml = "<tag>just a sample here</tag>"; 
  myxml = $(myxml); 
  if (window.ActiveXObject){ 
    var xmlString = myxml.xml; 
  } else {
    var oSerializer = new XMLSerializer(); 
    var xmlString = oSerializer.serializeToString(myxml[0]); // <-- HERE!
  } 
  console.log(xmlString); 
})
</script>
```